# There's any way to know the IP of a query sender?

Tags: mysql

I need to create a store procedure to save the last IP that call the store procedure and save it on a field.

Something like

```
UPDATE Users.LogIn SET lastIP=GET_REMOTE_IP(),lastLogin=NOW()
WHERE UserID=user AND GroupID=group;
```

Can be that posible?

I found INET_ATON() and INET_NTOA() but they are for converting purposes.

Comment: This IP address should be a parameter of the procedure and the script that executes the `CALL your_procedure('172.16.1.5')` got to supply this parameter, wherever it got it from.

Comment: I can't edit the code of the application that is sending the query to my server, I just manage the database.

Comment: I shouldn't ever think in terms of a web application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(host, ':', 1) AS 'ip' FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE ID=connection_id();`

This will also remove the port from the result.